# Google sheet array formula sumif only the first instance

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi Im using this formula to get the amount of time for each day

```
=arrayformula(If(C2:C="","",sumif(C2:C&D2:D,C2:C&D2:D,B2:B20)))
```

but I would need it to only sum up the amount for each day on the first instance of that day
as shown in column F and leave all other instance blank

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, E2:E, ))
```